# Angular Using NgBusy with a BehaviorSubject and ExhaustMap

Tags: angular

What would be the best practice when using [ng-busy](https://github.com/victos/angular-opensource/tree/master/projects/ng-busy) with more complex RxJS operators like `switchMap` or `exhaustMap` on a `BehaviorSubject` without subscribing to an observable within a subscribe block?

If you set this.busy on the `BehaviorSubject` it will always be busy since it's going off the `BehaviorSubject` not the Http request subscription.

```
public currentPage$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);

// ...

// Not sure how to use "busy" this way:
this.currentPage$
  .pipe(
    exhaustMap((page: number = 1) =>
      (page) ? this.getAlerts(page) : empty()
    ),
    map((response: HttpResponse<Alert[]>) => 
      response.results
    )
  )
  .subscribe(
    (alerts: Alert[]) => { ... },
    (error: any) => { ... }
  );
```

As I understand from articles like [this](https://medium.com/@paynoattn/3-common-mistakes-i-see-people-use-in-rx-and-the-observable-pattern-ba55fee3d031) the below code is not best practice when using observables, but I don't see how else to do it.

> But it’s like Observableception, right? No. Observables do not like
>   being inside Observables.

```
this.currentPage$
  .subscribe(
    (page: number = 1) => {

     // Can use "busy" this way:
     this.busy = this.getAlerts(page)
        .pipe(
          map((response: HttpResponse<Alert[]>) => 
            response.results
          )
        )
        .subscribe(
          (alerts: Alert[]) => { ... },
          (error: any) => { ... }
        );
    },
    (error: any) => { ... }
  );
```

Comment: So many spaces dude, I can't even read it, lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to fire side-effects inside a piped stream, the `tap` operator is the goto:

```
this.currentPage$.pipe(
  exhaustMap((page: number = 1) => { 
    if(page) {
      const obs$ = this.getAlerts(page).pipe(share());
      this.busy = obs$.subscribe();
      return obs$;
    } else
      return empty();
  }),
  map((response: HttpResponse<Alert[]>) => response.results),
).subscribe(
  (alerts: Alert[]) => { ... },
  (error: any) => { ... }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it would work, but if you did this in slightly different example where the `exhaustMap` param was falsey and `empty()` was returned the request wouldn't occur and the second `tap` would never be invoked.  Also, if the request failed I'd need to repeat the unsubscribe in the finally block of the subscribe to guarantee the unsubscribe was invoked.  Seems like it would be better to tie this to the Http request if possible.

Comment: @mtpultz to tie something to a http request use a http interceptor but then again inside the interceptor you will have to account fo r next, error, and complete events. https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: That would also mean handling multiple requests in a queue, and setting up a global service to share the busy subscription.

Comment: @mtpultz Hmmm... Okay this should do it. Now it is directly tied to the http observable and using `share()` prevents multiple subscriptions causing multiple HTTP requests.